# trying to graph a function with x and e(constant ?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}  1-|x|/e ,\quad |x| \leqslant e  \\ 0, \qquad \qquad  e< 
 |x| \leqslant 1 \end{cases} $$

$$ where\qquad 0< e < 1 $$

I assume e is a constant and e will not run from 0 to 1. But x will go from 0 to 1. 
I attempted a graph trying to understand the function.

DATA:(x)

octave:23>
x =

Columns 1 through 7:

```
0.00000    0.05000    0.10000    0.15000    0.20000    0.25000    0.30000
```

Columns 8 through 14:

```
0.35000    0.40000    0.45000    0.50000    0.55000    0.60000    0.65000
```

Columns 15 through 19:

```
0.70000    0.75000    0.80000    0.85000    0.90000
```

=================================================

( y = 1 - x/.9)  I took e= .9 
so e is $$ 0<e<1 $$

DATA:(y)

octave:24> 
y =

Columns 1 through 8:

1.00000   0.94444   0.88889   0.83333   0.77778   0.72222   0.66667   0.61111

Columns 9 through 16:

0.55556   0.50000   0.44444   0.38889   0.33333   0.27778   0.22222   0.16667

Columns 17 through 19:

0.11111   0.05556   0.00000

[The graph of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOiHS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $[0,e)$, it is a line segment $$y=1-\frac{x}{e},$$

It has slope $-\frac1e$ and intercept $1$.

Also, this is an even function, On $(-e,0]$, it is a line segment $$y=1+\frac{x}{e},$$

It has slope $\frac1e$ and intercept $1$.

It is zero everywhere else.

[image]

Remark: $e$ need not be a good choice of notation in general.

Comment: so "|x|" suggest that 'x' goes in both direction , positive and negative ?

Comment: $|x|$ is the absolute value function. $|-0.5|=0.5=|0.5|$. It remove the sign and returns the length.

Comment: Thank you!!!! very much.